# Loading Google Charts with jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile, google-visualization

I am working on a jQuery Mobile application and trying to implement Google Charts.  I cannot get the chart to display with my current approach.  It loads fine if I place all the code in the head, but when I transfer it to my main.js file, it does not show up.

Basic HTML Page I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Manufacturing Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/grey-orange.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.custom.structure.min" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["piechart", "corechart", "geomap"]});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="main-project-page">
        <div data-role="panel" class="project-menu" data-position="left" data-theme="c">
        </div><!-- /panel --> 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <h3 id="project-name"></h3>
            <div id="project-overall-chart"></div>
        </div><!-- /content --> 
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        </div><!-- /footer --> 
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling an API to send me some info about the project from a database, and with that information I create my chart.  However, I am just using the example from Google's API Documentation right now as a place holder to make sure I understand it.  This is how I am trying to call it...

```
//Global thingz
var request;
var project_id = "null";
var equipment_id = "null";

//Main Project Page
$(document).on("pageinit", "#main-project-page", function() {

    //Menu Panel slide effect
    $('.menu-button').click(function(event) {
        $('.project-menu').panel("open");
    });

    //Populate project page with current project...
    populate_project_view();


});

function populate_project_view()
{
    //If there is a project to get
    if (project_id != 'null')
    {
        //Construct the JSON
        var json = new Object();
        var info = new Object();

        json.type = "info";
        info.type = "project";
        info.id = project_id;
        json.info = info;

        json = JSON.stringify(json);

        //Make-a the request-a
        request = getHTTPObject();
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //If request object received response
            if (request.readyState == 4)
            {
                var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                if (json.error == true)
                {
                    alert('Error: ' + json.msg);
                    //Revert back to main screen
                    $.mobile.changePage('#main-page', 'slide', true, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Populate the #main-project-page DOM with project object
                    var project = json.project;

                    //Populate Project's name
                    var name = document.createTextNode(project.name);
                    $('#project-name').append(name);

                    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                    // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
                    // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
                    // draws it.
                    function drawChart() {

                        // Create the data table.
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
                        data.addRows([
                          ['Mushrooms', 3],
                          ['Onions', 1],
                          ['Olives', 1],
                          ['Zucchini', 1],
                          ['Pepperoni', 2]
                        ]);

                        // Set chart options
                        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                                       'width':400,
                                       'height':300};

                        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('project-overall-chart'));
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("GET", "./php/api.php?package=" + json + '&qs=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
        request.send(null);
    }
}

/*
    Support functions 
*/

//Returns an HTTPObject
function getHTTPObject()
{
    var xhr = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        try
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                xhr = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

I'm not very experienced with JavaScript's AJAX operations and it's overall activity in the browser yet, still trying to get a better grasp on all of that.  Thanks in advance for any help with this problem!

Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  Instead of setting a callback to fire once the API has loaded, because the way I am using it, it should always be loaded by the time I am trying to use a chart, I just fire off the `drawChart()` function when needed.

Changed

```
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    //Code here...
}
```

To

```
*Main Function* {
    drawChart();
}

function drawChart() {
    //Code here...
}
```